# How to use firebase cloud function properly

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am using the firebase cloud function in my app, I am still learning it, so from the tutorials, I am using, I want to give a user a custom claim in the cloud function but I got this error in the console.

Here is the error I got.

```
Error: internal
    at new y (error.ts:66)
    at w (error.ts:175)
    at A.<anonymous> (service.ts:263)
    at tslib.es6.js:100
    at Object.next (tslib.es6.js:81)
    at r (tslib.es6.js:71)
```

Here is the client-side code

```
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
           <input class="form-control mr-sm-2 makeAdminInput" type="email" placeholder="Users Email" required>
           <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary my-2 my-sm-0 makeAdminBtn" type="submit">Make Admin</button>
        </form>
      <script>
       $(document).ready(() => {
        functions = firebase.functions()
        $('.makeAdminBtn').click(e => {
            e.preventDefault()
            let email = $('.makeAdminInput').val()
            let addAdminRole = functions.httpsCallable('addAdminRole')
            addAdminRole({ email }).then(resp =>console.log(resp)).catch(error => console.log(error))
        })
</script>
```

The cloud function code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin')

admin.initializeApp()
exports.addAdminRole = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
    return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email).then(user => {
        return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, { admin: true })
    }).then(() => {
        return { message: `Success ${data.email} has being made admin` }
    }).catch(err => { return err })
})
```

Please what am I doing that is wrong, I am still new to firebase

Comment: Your code seems correct at first sight. You should adapt your code in order to return an error that is meaningful. So far we cannot see what is the error because you don't return an instance of `functions.https.HttpsError`. Adapt your code following https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors and https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors_on_the_client. Also, do you see any error message in the Cloud Function log on the Firebase console?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec yes this is the error `addAdminRole
Function execution took 77 ms, finished with status code: 400`

Comment: Ok, can you adapt the CF as explained above in order to get a more meaningful error message?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec `addAdminRole Invalid request, unable to process`

Comment: what is CF, i am still new to firebase

Comment: CF = your Cloud Function ;-)  please adapt the code as explained in  https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors. Also, are you sure you are passing an existing user email??

Comment: Yes i am passing an existing email

Comment: Can you debug with `.then(user => { console.log(user.uid); ...})` and check you correctly get the user id in the Cloud Function log on the Firebase console?

Comment: I'm marking this as a duplicate for now because there is a known problem with some recent versions of the Firebase client SDK.  Be sure to upgrade to the latest 7.22.1 to see if that helps.